# Сервер присылает Content-Type: application/javascript

Tags: c++, curl

Пытаюсь получить веб-страницу используя cURL + C++. Делаю Get-запрос и получаю такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я должен запустить эту функцию? Что мне ему слать в ответе?

Comment: А точно страницу просил?

Comment: Первый запрос Get - прислал ответ 401 (не идентифицирован) и кинул мне в теле ссылку. Я делаю следующий запрос на этот URL и он мне присылает этот ответ. Видимо эта функция должна мне создать куки, которые я должен буду отправить в POST следующим шагом. Вот как мне запустить эту функцию?

Comment: Сервер, к которому Вы обращаетесь, рассчитан на работу с браузером. Браузер, получив страницу с js - функцией, умеет её запускать. Дальше - эта функция уже сама будет что то делать с сайтом - например, обращаться к методам бэкэнда на нём. curl этого делать не умеет.

Comment: Писать обработчик JS, и вообще свой браузер... :(

Comment: То есть курлом такую страницу не получить?

Comment: curl треанспорт, а страница - груз, который он перевозит. Так что curl тут ни при чем.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала выполнить полученное в браузере и посмотреть, что оно делает. Может там и получиться вытянуть то, что нужно. Так же перепотрошите список загрузки первонвчальной страницы в браузере. Может там найдется то, что можно запрашивать сразу, без промежуточных манипуляций.